# php непонятка с функцией array_key_exists

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу сделать блог.

Дошел до уровня редактирования\добавления записей и категорий, но столкнулся с проблемой, которая никак не решается.

Написал простой код, который в случае существующей категории добавляет запись, а если заполненная в форме категория не найдена, создает эту категорию и добавляет туда запись.
Но, что-то когда код заходит в функцию `array_key_exists`, он уже оттуда не выходит. То есть, если категория не найдена, все нормально создает, а если найдена, то не выполняется почему-то.

```
else
$category_=$_POST["category"];
$titles=$_POST["title"];
$contents=$_POST["content"];

if (!array_key_exists($category_,$row))
{ $comand="CREATE TABLE $category_ (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,content VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
data TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,PRIMARY KEY (id))";
$result=mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
$comand="INSERT INTO $category_ (title, content) VALUES ('$titles','$contents')";
$result=mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
}
else{
$comand="INSERT INTO $category_ (title, content) VALUES ('$titles','$contents')";
$result=mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: У вас в коде есть вложенные циклы и условия, но отступов нет и структуру кода сложно воспринимать. Когда публикуете код в вопросе, пожалуйста, форматируйте его. Большинство IDE умеют делать это по нажатию кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

В общем и целом Ваш код правильный и должен работать. Дело скорее всего во вводимых данных. Например, непонятно, что за `$row`? Может быть `array_key_exists()` всегда `false`? Таким образом в первый раз таблица создается, а во второй Вы пытаетесь создать уже существующую, что обрезает выполнение...

Еще я бы советовал Вам кое-что изменить.

```
if (!array_key_exists($category_,$row))
{
    $comand="CREATE TABLE $category_ (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,content VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    data TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    $result=mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
}
$comand="INSERT INTO $category_ (title, content) VALUES ('$titles','$contents')";
$result=mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
```

Т.е. в Вашем коде `INSERT INTO` дважды, хотя в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: пообрезал..но ответ так и не нашел,, переписал по другому...в цикле построчно проверяю название в массиве, если оно есть то добавляю запись и тупо прекращаю работу кода дальше.......